# I want to display name in front of field instead of

Tags: python, django, django-forms

..whatdoyoucallitanyway..

I have this model:

```
class Kaart(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, name="Kaardi peakiri", help_text="Sisesta kaardi pealkiri (maksimum tähemärkide arv on 38)", blank=False, null=False)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False, name="Asukoha URL", help_text="Täisasukoht (http://www.domeen.ee/kaart/)")
    kirjeldus = models.TextField(max_length=500, name="Kommentaar", help_text="Informatsioon / viide tegijale (mitte kohustuslik)")
```

Then i have this form:

```
class KaartForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Kaart
```

And i have this code in my template:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <p>
    <label>{{ field.label }}</label>
    <em>{{ field.help_text }}</em>
    {{ field }}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that both field.label and field.name display name, url, kirjeldus instead of the names i have set for them - "Kaardi pealkiri" etc. How do i get to use those instead?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use `verbose_name` instead of `name` in your model.

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Kaardi peakiri", help_text="Sisesta kaardi pealkiri (maksimum tähemärkide arv on 38)", blank=False, null=False)
```

[See the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/). There is no option called `name`.

Comment: Guess i was reading bit wrong docs. was reading generic field and form field docs...

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types), the `ModelForm`'s widget pulls its `label` value from the `verbose_name` attribute.